# can't monetize my app on admob

Tags: android, admob

I am a beginner at using admob with android app and I have already created an admob account but I can't monetize my app because I haven't uploaded my app on the market because there is no ad unit in my app, and to make an ad unit code you have to monetize your uploaded app on the market, so I don't how to deal with this issue.

should I upload my app on the market without any ad and after that menotize it and then add the ad unit to my app by updating it in the market ?

Comment: There is a new network called Appodeal. They offer immediate payouts and eCPMs higher than 7$. You should consider to give it a chance ;) http://appodeal.com/+register

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to publish your app before integrating ad units.

You can "Add your app manually".

[image: Add your app manually]

Ad units will be generated after adding your app. Integrate it in your app and publish it.

After 48hrs of publishing to the play store, you can then "link your app".

[image: Link your app]

To prevent click fraud(which leads to account bans), make sure you don't click the ads. However, if you want to click on the ads when testing, use test devices ids.

Example:

```
  AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
    .build();
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Hey, if I add apps to my application, but I don't actually monetize it in admob, will I still get the money for the clicks? I released an app last month, and I realized now, that I didn't monetize it. The publisher ID and everything was properly put into my code, so it should still be linked to my admob, right? So what does monetizing even do anyway? If I don't monetize, will I still get the money earned? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144741/what-will-happen-with-these-ads