# What will happen with these Ads?

Tags: android, click, admob, ads, impressions

If I add Ads apps to my application, but I don't actually monetize it in Admob, will I still get the money for the clicks? I released an app last month, and I realized now, that I didn't monetize it in the actual Admob website. The publisher ID and everything was properly put into my code, so it should still be linked to my Admob, right? So what does monetizing even do anyway? If I don't monetize, will I still get the money earned?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

> If I add Ads apps to my application, but I don't actually monetize it
>   in Admob, will I still get the money for the clicks?

What do you mean by add ads but not monetize? When you add ads you automatically monetize. (Unless you are using someone else's ad unit ids - in this case you are still monetizing but someone else is earning revenue.) dont do that. Earn for yourself :-)

> The publisher ID and everything was properly put into my code, so it
>   should still be linked to my Admob, right?

Yes, it should be linked.

> So what does monetizing even do anyway?

Monetizing means adding the ads in your app.

> If I don't monetize, will I still get the money earned?

No. If you dont monetize you dont earn, obviously. But from what you say, you have already monetized your app.

Comment: By monetize I mean clicking the button on my actual admob account that says 'monetize new app'. Then I search for my app and add it.

Comment: That will help you create the ad units. You actually monetize when you put those ad units in your app code and display ads.

Comment: And what does clicking the monetize button in admobs website do then?

Comment: Nothing... Just takes you to the monetize page.